# How to filter api data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filter

So i'm trying to filter my star wars api data through a searchbox and got this so far :

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      jedi: [],
      searchfield: ''
    }
  }


  // Loop through API
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
      .then(response => { return response.json()})
      .then(people => this.setState({jedi:people}))
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value})
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }   

  render() {
    const {jedi, searchfield} = this.state;
    const filteredCharacters = jedi.filter(jedi => {
      return jedi.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
    })
  }
}
```

This is my SearchBox component

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox = ({searchfield, searchChange})=> {
  return (
    <div className= 'searchbox1'>
      <input className = 'searchbox2' 
        type = 'search' 
        placeholder = 'search character'
        onChange = {searchChange} 
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export {SearchBox};
```

This is the render in the main app component

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={lightsaber} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
        <h1 className="App-title">
          Star Wars Character App w/API
        </h1>
      </header>  

      <SearchBox searchChange= {this.onSearchChange} />

      <div className = 'allcards'>
        <Card jedi = {this.filteredCharacters}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

It keeps giving me the error "jedi.filter is not a function'. Initially I figured since filter only works on Arrays and my data were strings, that i'd use `jedi.split('').filter`. But that didnt seem to work as I just got "jedi.split isnt a function". What's going on?

Comment: The api call that you're making in `componentDidMount` results in an object, not an array or a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the code this link 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1' returns a single object (Luke Skywalker). You can't use .filter() on an object it is meant for arrays of data.

```
{name: "Luke Skywalker", height: "172", mass: "77", hair_color: "blond", skin_color: "fair", …}
```

When I change the url 'https://swapi.co/api/people/' and remove the 1 I receive an object with another array of objects inside `results`.

I am assuming you want to search through a list of Jedis. If you want the list returned in the API you have to dig a step further into this object inside results. So you need to refactor your fetch as follows:

```
.then(people => this.setState({ jedi:people.results }))
```

This returns 10 objects inside of an array.

Once you have an array of these objects you can use the `lodash` library to filter through. `npm i lodash` and require it in as `import _ from 'lodash'`.

Then in your render right after your destructure you can run the following filter.

```
const filtered = _.filter(jedi, (item) => {
   return item.name.indexOf(searchfield) > -1
})

console.log(filtered)
```

I am assuming after this you will be returning the list of filtered Jedis to the UI

I hardcoded 'Luke' in my search field state and it returned 1 Jedi successfully